# CSS. Как масштабировать div вместе с содержимым под высоту экрана?

Tags: css, масштабирование

Я могу масштабировать div вместе с содержимым вот так:

```
.my_div {
    zoom: .9;
}
```

Но как сделать чтобы уровень масштабирования устанавливался сам соответственно высоте экрана?

Я пробовал делать так:

```
.my_div {
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
}
```

Но тогда масштабируется только сам div, а контент с текстом и изображениями может вылезать за его пределы (объём контента внутри div непредсказуем). Есть ли способ использовать нечто условно вроде вот такого:

```
zoom: 100vh;
```

?

Дополнение:

Я хотел использовать медиа-запросы, но насколько я понял, они просто возвращают мне ответ "да" или "нет" на мой вопрос о том, попадает ли текущая высота или ширина окна в некий указанный мной диапазон, например 500px.

Допустим я получил ответ, что высота экрана меньше 500px.
И как мне это поможет?
Указать для каждой высоты экрана определённое значение `zoom`?

Но я не могу заранее предсказать каков будет контент блока, а значит и какова будет его высота, а значит и какое значение `zoom` мне использовать чтобы блок идеально вписался в окно браузера.

Мне нужно найти способ динамического изменения свойства CSS 'zoom', при котором блок my_div будет масштабироваться (уменьшаться или увеличиваться) под текущую высоту экрана вместе со всем содержимым (размер текста также должен масштабироваться). Я подозреваю что на чистом CSS это сделать не выйдет.

Comment: есть : медиа запросы ...

Comment: написал дополнение в вопрос по поводу медиа-запросов

Comment: Не понял задачи, нужно четко привязать пропорции, или ограничить ширину контента?

Comment: Вопрос совсем не понятен. Нужно, чтоб `my_div` был растянут на 100% высоты и при изменении объема содержимого расширялся вниз? Или увеличивался при наведении? Или, чтоб родитель вписывался в экран, а содержимое внутри прокручивалось, при увеличении объема?

Comment: Мне нужно найти способ динамического изменения свойства CSS 'zoom',  при котором блок my_div будет масштабироваться (уменьшаться или увеличиваться) под текущую высоту экрана. Я подозреваю что на чистом CSS это сделать не выйдет.

Answer (score 2):

Вот первый блок с пропорцией 2x1, второй с контентом всегда на 100% не выходящий за рамки

```js
const input = document.getElementById('widthOne');
const div = document.getElementById('one');

input.addEventListener('change', ()=>{
  div.style.width = input.value + 'px';
  div.style.height = 'calc(' + input.value + 'px / 2)';
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.one {
  width: 100vw;
  background: skyblue;
  height: calc(100vw / 2);
  position: relative; // лишнее
}

.one span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.content100 {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.content100 h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.content100>* {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
Ширина первого блока: <input id="widthOne" type="number" step="1"/>

<div class="one" id="one">
  <span>2x1</span>
</div>

<div class="content100">
  <h2>Контент всегда 100% любой</h2>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496092607007-ca127e0b6a10?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=785&q=80">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Incidunt similique saepe aliquam quaerat laborum omnis corrupti velit, nam corporis quae facilis vitae quod voluptas, odit doloremque. Eum illum, cupiditate, quod omnis unde eligendi laudantium
    quisquam tempora nihil magnam totam atque consequatur autem aspernatur sapiente quae. In, reiciendis. Rem, iste possimus!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Не сразу разобрался что вы имели ввиду (там, кстати, в классе 'one' у вас высота рассчитывается по ширине). Суть я понял, но размер текста при таком подходе не масштабируется. Свойство 'zoom' позволило бы это сделать, но в отличие от 'height' его нельзя установить в еденицах типа 'vh' или '%'. Нужен простенький скрипт.

Comment: вы хотите чтобы не блоки а текст уменьшался в масштабе?

Comment: И сам блок и абсолютно всё что внутри

Answer (score 0):

**Попробуй выставить:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Я пробовал нечто подобное, это будет изменение высоты, текст в контенте не будет масштабироваться.

Comment: А если выставить font-size в процентах?

Comment: Можно установить высоту `body` в `100vh`, высоту `my_div` в `100%` и его `font-size` тоже в `%` как вы и говорите. Но, при изменении высоты `body` будет изменяться лишь высота `my_div`, но не текст. Не знаю почему.

Можно установить `font-size` в `vh`.
Но и тут проблема, значение выбранное для `font-size` действительно установит пропорцию межу текстом и высотой 'my_div' и они действительно будут вместе изменяться при изменении высоты 'body'. Но проблема в том, что текст внутри 'my_div' может меняться, а при другом тексте должен быть и другой 'font-size'.

Answer (score 0):

На чистом CSS не знаю как, сделал скрипт:

```
setInterval( () => {

    let winHeight = $(window).height();     // высота окна
    let divHeight = $('.my_div').height();  // высота блока
    let ratio = winHeight / divHeight;      // отношение между ними
    $('.my_div').css({ zoom: ratio });      // масштабирование блока 

}, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно повесить обработчик события на resize окна и с помощью css transform: scale() изменять масштаб объекта как хотите. Zoom не имеет официальной поддержки и его лучше не использовать.

Ещё есть вариант использовать:
`<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height" />`
c установкой соответствующего height для блока.